# CIDR security group in aws ec2 configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, cidr

My website seems to be under heavy bandwidth which is hosted in EC2 AWS.

May I know how to determine CIDR for an area/country so that traffic can be limited in the security group configuration for aws ec2.

My current IP from my internet provider is this:
124.13.126.1

Is it possible to limit it to this area/country ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow your ISP Ip range by adding this 124.13.126.1/32. to inbound security group

Or you can use aws WAF to only allow users in your region https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-geo-conditions.html